# How to serve static files in node js strapi js and angular 5 project

Tags: node.js, angular5, strapi

I am trying to setup static files serving in nodejs,strapijs and angular 5 project.
In strapi by default it is serving static files from public folder. When i refresh the page I am getting the error as path not found. If i gives the base url it is working fine but if i give any other page url it is throwing path not found error.
My project folder structure is 
Root Directory-
 --API
 --Public
 --UI

Comipled code from the Angular UI project will present in  Public folder and Strapi framework is serving the files from the Public folder.
For the first time app is loading fine without any issues and it is displaying the landing page. If we refresh the URL it is throwing path not found error.

Comment: that seems like an error. However, strapi is a headless cms and API, UI content should be served some where else outside Strapi.

Answer (score 1):

To serve this time of application and handle refresh, you will have to use the same way as the admin panel (React application) is served.

So where take a look:
- List of routing to serve admin files (https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi/lib/middlewares/public/index.js#L63)
- How to create a custom middleware in your project (https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/middlewares/users-permissions)

Now what you have to do is to create a middleware in your application and add a list of routing to serve your Angular5 application assets

Comment: Does this means i need a custom route for the app and not '/' ? Also, can you link to a static tree please, because that file is changed and no longet L63